# Replace some text with different values using PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, random, preg-replace, str-replace, uniqueidentifier

I want to know how to replace some text in php string to different values using preg_replace.

For example :

- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456
- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456
- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456

I want this result :

- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=456789
- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=789456
- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=159753

I have used this code :

```
$string = 'http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456<br/>
            http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456<br/>
            http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456';

$string = preg_replace(array("~123456~", "~123456~", "~123456~"), array("456789","789456","159753"), $string);

echo $string;
```

but it gives me this result :

- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=456789
- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=456789
- http://www.mysite.com/?uid=456789

Any help ?

Thanks !

Comment: How are you getting the uid numbers in the result you want? They look random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$string = 'http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456<br/>
        http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456<br/>
        http://www.mysite.com/?uid=123456';

$newString = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]{6})/im', function($matches){ return rand(100000, 999999); }, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can test `"~http://www\.mysite\.com/\?uid\=([0-9]+)~si"` it find all with different  `uid` value  and you can use `preg_replace_callback` for check and replace them